# Accessing an instance method variable within another instance variable in the same class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and am having this problem of accessing variables within same class but different instance variables

```
class A

  def x
    @z = params[:something]
    #someother code i dont 
  end

  def y
    #self.x returns the full instance method but i just want @z without the entire method
  end
end
```

how do i do this

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your method `x` is called before the method `y` you can just use `@z` to get the instance variable

Comment: This is very helpful but i wonder is there a better solution?